# Rails: Retrieving polymorphic data from nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, controller

I'm trying to retrieve data for all items from a box, a box can have compartments and I'd like  to get all compartment info at the box level. items are made polymorphic as boxes won't necessarily have compartments.

MODEL

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :compartments
  has_many :items, :as => :itemable
end
```

In my Controller I can get results back with:

```
@box = Box.find(params[:id])

@itemable = @box.compartments.first

@itemable = @box.compartments.last
```

VIEW

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<%= item.name %>
<% end %>
```

but if I then try

```
@itemable = @box.compartments
```

OR

```
@itemable = @box.compartments.find(:all)
```

I get the error

```
undefined method `items' for #<ActiveRecord::Array>
```

OR

```
undefined method `items' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation>
```

Can anyone help with getting results back from all compartments?

Comment: Might you need to use `.itemables`, per `:as => :itemable`?

Comment: Did you define 'belongs_to' in Itemable and Compartment classes?

Comment: @megas items are polymorphic, so in Compartments I have: has_many :items, :as => :itemable too

Comment: I don't understand, what is the relation between Box and Compartment? Why you've defined polymorphic connection but don't using it in your code?

Comment: @megas A compartment belongs to a box, items are polymorphic so they can also belong to a box instance that doesn't necessarily have compartments. My issue here is that I want to see info from an instance of a box which has two containers, and to see those containers' items in the box view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in compartments you have

```
belongs_to :box
has_many :items, :as => :itemable
```

Is this the case?  `@box.compartments` should return an array of compartments right?  It sounds like `items` is somehow getting called on `@box.compartments` somehow

Comment: Yes, Compartment belongs_to Box. I've noticed the error changes with @box.compartments to undefined method `items' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: after [@box.compartments] I can do [@items = @itemable.first.items], so the array seems to work - I just need to figure out out how to loop this in the controller, I think?

Comment: I thought `@itemable = @box.compartments` threw an error, so you couldn't try `@itemable.first.items`

Comment: You're right, I was trying a few things out and after [@itemable = @box.compartments] I got it to work by adding [@items = @itemable]